# Extract Column(s) from text file having Multi Character Delimiter i.e. "%$%"

Tags: linux, file, awk, command

I have tried different solution for the problem given on the forum but doesn't work for the specified Delimiter `%$%`, I need to extract one specific column from the file containing 200+ columns.

I tried the following:

```
awk -F"%$%" '{print $1}' sample.txt > outfile.txt
awk 'gsub("%$%",":")' sample.txt > outfile.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symbol `$` is a special character in a regex, so you need to escape it with a `\`, which is also a special character for the string literal, so it needs to be escaped again.

So, finally we have:

```
$ cat sample 
ghkjlj;lk%$%23e;k32poek%$%eqdje2oijd%$%xrgtdy5h

$ awk -F'%\\$%' '{print $1}' sample 
ghkjlj;lk
```

Answer (score 1):

no matter `-F (FS)` or `gsub()`, it expects a regex, you need either use character class or escape those chars with special meaning, like `$` in your example.

```
kent$ awk -F'%[$]%' '{print $1}' <<<"foo%$%bar%$%blah"
foo
```

If you just want to change the separator, you can do with `gsub` or using `OFS`:

```
kent$ awk -F'%[$]%' -v OFS=":" '$1=$1' <<<"foo%$%bar%$%blah"
foo:bar:blah  
kent$ awk 'gsub(/%[$]%/,":")+1' <<<"foo%$%bar%$%blah"  
foo:bar:blah
```